# STM32F3 Write in FLASH HAL_FLASH

Tags: stm32

I'm trying to save values in the FLASH memory, but only save 0x00000000 values... I've implemented erase command in order to preform flash_program command. I'm using a NUCLEO64 - STM32F303RE... The problem is that the values don't are save.

```
if(HAL_FLASH_Unlock() != HAL_OK)
{
    debugPrintln(&huart2, "HAL UNLOCK ERROR");
}

FLASH_PageErase(0);

if(HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, (uint32_t) 0x08000000, (uint32_t) 0x01) != HAL_OK)
{
    debugPrintln(&huart2, "HAL WRITE ERROR 1");
}
if(HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, 0x08000004, (uint32_t) 0x00000000) != HAL_OK)
{
    debugPrintln(&huart2, "HAL WRITE ERROR 2");
}

if(HAL_FLASH_Lock() != HAL_OK)
{
    debugPrintln(&huart2, "HAL lOCK ERROR");
}
```

After the execution, the maps is next:

Comment: https://ibb.co/zrw31bp

Comment: Please, include picture into the question itself. Also, please give a better explanation of what's going on. Flash page erase works? I see all 0xFF in the picture, so it must be ok. Write fails? Try two things: 1) add some delay between operations with flash and see if anything changes (CPU is faster than flash). Start with really long delay just to test the method, like 1s. 2) put a breakpoint after the first flash write, go to debug, open flash registers (SFR tab), find FLASH, find status or interrupt&status register (IR/ISR typically), some bit will be "1" there, under some specific error.

Comment: You didn't even say if your error debugPrintln actually prints anything, please, specify that.

Comment: Please, participate in discussion if you still want it solved